# Combining AND statements with regexmatch

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that will spit out 'True' or 'False' based on certain conditions.

I'd like the formula to spit out "True" if **all** the conditions below are met:

- Cell B14 contains either of the terms: "affinity|perception|perceptions|awareness|familiarity"
- Cell B53 is checked off (the cell has a check box)
- Cell B54 is checked off

I have this formula, below, but it doesn't seem to be doing what i want.

```
=IF((B53="true" AND( B54="true")),regexmatch(B14,"affinity|perception|perceptions|awareness|familiarity"))
```

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=and(B53<>"true", B54<>"true",regexmatch(B14,"affinity|perception|perceptions|awareness|familiarity"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by 'checked off' you mean that the checkbox is ticked? In this case

```
=and(B53,B54,regexmatch(B14,"affinity|perception|perceptions|awareness|familiarity"))
```

although you don't need to specify "perception" as well as "perceptions" because "perception" will pick up both.

[image]